# Why kexec-tools doesn't work? Is there someting I did wrong?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to use `kexec` and `kdump` to reboot system when it crash. I have set kexec and kdump config but it still not work. I have set `kernel.panic=10`. Did I do something wrong?

I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** and `kdump-config show` are as follow.

```
DUMP_MODE:        kdump
USE_KDUMP:        1
KDUMP_SYSCTL:     kernel.panic_on_oops=1
KDUMP_COREDIR:    /var/crash
crashkernel addr: 0x23000000
   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-25-generic
kdump initrd: 
   /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-25-generic
current state:    ready to kdump
```

`kexec` command:

```
/sbin/kexec -p --command-line="BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic root=UUID=9444b3a0-3ccc-4f57-8f51-bbf005963b11 ro quiet splash pci=nomsi pci=noaer pcie_aspm=off vt.handoff=1 nr_cpus=1 systemd.unit=kdump-tools-dump.service irqpoll nousb ata_piix.prefer_ms_hyperv=0" --initrd=/boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-25-generic
```

Could anyone give me some advice? tks

Comment: If you are using this in a virtual machine, you can set up serial console to output and save the logs of the guest system. This might help analyze the problem in case the kexec'ed kernel hangs or crashes itself, for example. And, what exactly does not work? Does the system reboot after a kernel crash? Or, perhaps, it reboots but does not save the dump? Or something else?

Comment: @Eugene It just stuck there, I don't know if there is a reboot. And I check the log, nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: Are you trying to run kexec directly or are you triggering a kernel crash somehow? How? If you tried running kexec directly, please check if crashing the kernel with 'echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger' triggers reboot and saving of the dump.

Comment: @Eugene I'm trying to triggering a kernel crash to test its function also I have tried to run it directly but the results are same. Before I set kexec's config, kernel.panic still work but it failed after I set kexec. Do you think there's something wrong with the command I entered?

Comment: Or is there another way maybe like setting grub parameters to load another kernel when it crash? This is a difficulty for me in my homework.

Comment: Please show the contents of /proc/cmdline as well as the output of 'dmesg | grep crashkernel'.

Comment: dmesg | grep crashkernel  [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic root=UUID=9444b3a0-3ccc-4f57-8f51-bbf005963b11 ro crashkernel=256M quiet splash pci=nomsi pci=noaer pcie_aspm=off crashkernel=512M-:192M vt.handoff=1  
[    0.010061] Reserving 192MB of memory at 560MB for crashkernel (System RAM: 16291MB)
[    0.090992] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic root=UUID=9444b3a0-3ccc-4f57-8f51-bbf005963b11 ro crashkernel=256M quiet splash pci=nomsi pci=noaer pcie_aspm=off crashkernel=512M-:192M vt.handoff=1

Comment: /proc/cmdline                                                                                               BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic  root=UUID=9444b3a0-3ccc-4f57-8f51-bbf005963b11 ro crashkernel=256M quiet splash pci=nomsi pci=noaer pcie_aspm=off crashkernel=512M-:192M vt.handoff=1